# How to search for a string with a plus (+) sign using HTML form with MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, url-encoding

I have a very simple form that allows the user to search for a company name.  One of the company names is "A+ Service".  How can I build the form to encode the plus (+) sign prior to submitting the form, to allow for the user to input "A+" and find this company?

The form is submitting via POST.

A bit of background to help explain.  Here's the code for the form itself:

```
<form action="/search_customer.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"
      id="search_form" onsubmit="return validateSearch(document.search_form);">
Search Customers:
<input id="search_text1" name="global_search_text" type="text" value="">
<input type="submit" name="global_search" id="global_search" value="Go">
</form>
```

When we submit this form with "a+" as the search term, the resulting SQL is:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_customer
WHERE ( cus_fname LIKE '%a%' OR cus_lname LIKE '%a%');
```

My understanding is that we'll need to encode the value of the search string prior to submitting the form, but we're not clear on how to do this.

Comment: why do you need to encode anything ?

Comment: Are you searching for single company or multiple companies from a single input field?

Comment: Are you submitting form using `POST` or `GET` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is related to the `+` being translated as a space.

If you are sending the data using javascript, you could `encodeURIComponent` the value at first.

Comment: Not currently sending via JavaScript, @eridal, but I wasn't familiar with `encodeURLComponent()`, so I'll give that a try.

Comment: Added the following: `$('#search_text2').attr('name','global_search_text');
$('#search_text1').attr('name','global_search_text_decoded').keyup(function(){
$('#search_text2').val(encodeURIComponent($('#search_text1').val()));
});`

Answer (score 0):

Try using mysql_real_escape_string while writing search query pass the value as below... or show me your screenshot...

```
mysql_real_escape_string($value)
```